# Spark - Merging Multiple Map Columns with Common Keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a series of columns of the schemas `Map[(Int, Int), Row]` and `Map[(Int, Int), String]`, int-tuple keyed maps with some data (string or struct). I am attempting to take these columns, extract the data,  and insert it into a single column based on the keys via a UDF, as shown below.

```
case class PersonConcept(field1: Int, field2: Int, field3: String,
              field4: String, field5: String)

private def mergeMaps: UserDefinedFunction = {
  val f = (keyedData: Map[Row, Row], keyedNames: Map[Row, String],
                                keyedOccupations: Map[Row, String]) => {
    val intKeyedData = keyedData.map {
      case (row, data) =>
        (row.getInt(0), row.getInt(1)) -> data
    }
    val intKeyedNames = keyedNames.map {
      case (row, data) =>
        (row.getInt(0), row.getInt(1)) -> data
    }
    val intKeyedOccupations = keyedOccupations.map {
      case (row, data) =>
        (row.getInt(0), row.getInt(1)) -> data
    }
    intKeyedData
      .map {
        case (k, v) => {
          val value =
            PersonConcept(v.getInt(0),
              v.getInt(1),
              v.getString(2),
              intKeyedOccupations(k), // <--- Grabbing occupation
              intKeyedNames(k))       // <--- Grabbing name
          (k, value)
        }
      }
  }
  udf(f)
}
```

I know for a fact that each map contains the exact same set of keys. However, I am encountering a `NoSuchElementException`.

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: (24,75)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
```

The UDF works fine when the dataset consists of only one row or one partition, leading me to believe that this is somehow related to scross partition variable scope or closure (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-). What I don't understand what could be causing this, and whether or not there is a feasible way to do this leveraging this data model.

Comment: Can you share some test data of the initial `df`?

Comment: @CesarA.Mostacero working on it, however, checkpointing the data to parquet, reading from there, and then applying the UDF appears to be working. Still investigating why that might resolve it.